# How give authentication for functions inside a component?

Tags: angularjs, angular, typescript, routes

Inside my component there three functions as delete update and add. Then i want to give access to these three functions to different users. All of three for super user. Two of them for another one like that

Comment: if these functions are executed on the click of a button then you can show and hide those buttons on the basis of the role of the user.And for extra check you can write a check inside the function to look for user role and then execute the function if he has access

Answer (score 1):

I assume the currentUser is maintained as a session object. So,

```
delete(){
   if(currentUser.role === Admin) {
      ....
   } else {
            //error message
   }
}
```